# setting default option tag Selected rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I am generating a list of objects in a option tag using ruby rails .eg

```
 %optgroup
  -for @people in c do
    %option(value: cac,)
```

how do i specify a default for the option tag? like a place holder which says please select person, and also how do set it from a cookie or previous selected country.

thanks

Comment: Please take a look at the form helpers http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work(not sure what objects you are working with so the attribute names may need to be changed):

```
 %optgroup
   -for @people in c do
     -if c.id == default.id
       %option{value: c.value, selected: true}
     -else
       %option{value: c.value}
```

But the helper that @Iceman linked you allows you to do this in a much simpler way. (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select)

Comment: thanks exactly what i wanted but how would i set default as select person... .